# color react-force-graph links based on value with d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graph, three.js

i want to create an app with a 3D Force Graph made with this project:
https://github.com/vasturiano/react-force-graph

You can find my example based on the Documentation on Github here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-sea-c7hj95?file=/index.html

My issue is, that i can't figure out how to color the links. I tried to set a static linkColor like so:

```
      linkColor = {"green"}
```

Which doesn't seem to work already. My goal would be to set the link colors based on the edge weight (value):

```
      linkColor = {"d3.interpolateViridis(colorScale(value)))"}
```

Maybe someone has an idea on how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get `linkColor` from? You're already assigning the color with

```js
sprite.color = node.color;
```

Just change that to whatever HEX value you'd like:

```js
sprite.color = "#ff9900"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! The linkColor is part of the react-force-graph API, which is described on github. The color i'm assigning you mentioned is the node Color. I would also like to change the color of the edges connecting the nodes. I think it would be ideal if i could define the links in the same way the nodes are defined. Thank you again!